# What is the role of each node in DolphinDB cluster? Can a controller or agent be used for in-memory computing?

Tags: hdfs, cluster-computing, dolphindb

I have deployed a single-server cluster (community edition) with 1 controller, 1 agent, and 2 data nodes.

**Question:** What is the role of each node? Can the controller or agent be used for in-memory computing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DolphinDB cluster has 4 types of nodes: controller, agent, data node, and compute node.

- **Controller:** There can be multiple controllers in a cluster. The controllers are the central nervous system of a DolphinDB cluster. They collect heartbeats of agents and data nodes, monitor the status of each node, and manage metadata and transactions of the distributed file system.
- **Agent:** An agent node executes the commands issued by a controller to
  start/stop local data nodes. Each physical server has one and only
  one agent within a cluster.
- **Data node:** Data are stored and queries (or more complex computations)
  are executed on data nodes. A physical server can be configured with
  multiple data nodes.
- **Compute node:** The compute node is only used for computation,
  including stream computing, distributed join and machine learning.
  Data is not stored on a compute node, and therefore you cannot create
  a database or table on it. However, you can use `loadTable` to load data from a data node to a compute node for computational work.

It is not recommended to perform in-memory computation in controller, because that would cause controller outage and then crash the whole cluster.